# Obtener un elemento usando agularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bueno amigos.
Estoy usando angular 1.6 y le he integrado ui-route para las vistas, este es mi codigo en el `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" >
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|PT+Sans|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-ui-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" ui-view="nav"></nav>
    <header id="header" class="area" ui-view="header"></header>
    <section id="page" class="area" ui-view="page"></section>
    <footer id="footer-main" ui-view="footer"></footer>
    <script src="assets/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Entonces, con ui-route cargo las vistas, cuando quiero capturar un elemento que estan dentro de esas vistas no me lo devuelve, los unicos que devuelve son los que estan en el `index.html`

Comment: Y como intentas capturar esos elementos?

Comment: he usando angular.element().find() y algunos otros que he visto en internet, como tambie estoy integrando jquery, con $(<selector>) tampoco agarra

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo del codigo de una vista donde tienes un elemento que quieres capturar? Un simple `angular.element(document.querySelector('_tu_selector')` deberia darte el objeto jQlite que necesitas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he resuelto mi problema, antes yo usaba

```
angular.element(document).find('.selector') // ejemplo
```

El problema es que el selector deberia ser una etiqueta, como lo es `div`, `section`, entre otros, y yo necesitaba era obtenerlos por id o por algun valor de un atributo. Como uso jquery usaba directamente `$('.selector')`, pero como el documento no estaba completamente cargado no me funcionaba.. asi que sonsegui este codigo que me funcionó

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selector')
})
```

Comment: Es perfectamente válido contestar tu propia pregunta, pero por favor no olvides marcarla también como **aceptada**.